# Replacing null with zero

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi I have following select command in SQL Server. I am trying to change it so if b.bId is null i want to assign it 0 value. So it displays 0 in the field.

```
select top 1
    a.sId
   ,b.bId  
    from tlocal a
    left outer join ts b on (b.id=a.mainId)
    where 
    a.id=@xId;
```

Please let me know how to modify. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the ISNULL function like so:

```
ISNULL(b.bId, 0) bId
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) Function

```
COALESCE(b.bId, 0) AS bId
```

[Performance: ISNULL vs. COALESCE](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/performance-isnull-vs-coalesce.aspx)

Comment: The link you have given, did not explain which  build-in function is faster.

Comment: @gotqn -- I guess you missed this part of the article: "I ran these tests several times on a few different servers, and ISNULL appears to pretty consistently out-perform COALESCE by an average of 10 or 12 percent. But that's the difference between 6 seconds and 5.3 seconds (the approximate average runtimes per test on my servers), over the course of a million exections(sp). Hardly worth the functionality and standards compliance sacrifice, at least in the scenarios I use these functions for."

Comment: Actually, the article is kind of old. If you did your research again, you will see that in newer version of SQL server there is no difference.

Comment: @gotqn then you should have posted that instead of your statement "The link you have given, did not explain which build-in function is faster." when the link quite clearly explains which function is faster.

Comment: Anyway, I am sure after these few post, people not to be mislead by the arctile anymore.

Answer (score 3):

As another alternative you could execute this sql at your `ts` table

```
update ts
set id = ''
where id is null
```

Comment: in the example provided the result of the field is null because of the join operation, which means that a matching result on the table was not found. COALESCE and ISNULL would be the optimal solutions in this case.